# java XML find the sibling node

Tags: java, xml

I have the below XML. Here I want to get the previous sibling of node c which is b using java

```
<root>
 <a>
   <b>
   <c>
   <d>
 </a>
</root>
```

Whenever I try to get the node using node.getPreviousSibling() method I get the node as #text but not the node b.

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of the java code you are using to parse the xml?

Comment: That's because there is a text node (containing all whitespace) between nodes `c` and `b`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like this:
(the #text that you get is the actual text in the node)

```
  public static Element getPreviousSiblingElement(Node node) {
      Node prevSibling = node.getPreviousSibling();
      while (prevSibling != null) {
          if (prevSibling.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
              return (Element) prevSibling;
          }
          prevSibling = prevSibling.getPreviousSibling();
      }

      return null;  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop...

```
while (node!= null && !(node instanceOf Element)) {
    node = node.getPreviousSibling();
}
```

You could also use an XPath expression, `./previous-sibling::*`